# Nuxt.js: `npm run generate` fails to generate `index.html`

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

All static routes and dynamic routes are generated, but not `index.html`. Why not?

In `nuxt-config.js` I have:

```
const staticRoutes =
  [
    '/about',
    '/contact',
    '/portfolio'
  ]
const dynamicRoutes = async () => {
  const routes = await axios.get('https://my-site.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.data.map((project) => `/project/${project.ID}/${project.post_name}`))

  return routes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your `dynamicRoutes` function to add the index `/` route in your `routes`:

```js
const dynamicRoutes = async () => {
  const routes = await axios.get('https://fabricepallaud.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.data.map((project) => `/project/${project.ID}/${project.post_name}`))

  routes.push("/")

  return routes
}
```

see https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module#using-top-level-options